# Layer Stacking in QGIS using Stack layer bands Option

Tags: qgis, layers, scp

I am doing layer stacking on LandSat 8 imagery using the SCP plugin of QGIS (3.16.11-Hannover release).

The problem is when I add all the required bands using the band set option and select the Stack Raster Bands option to stack my bands, it shows an error that occurred while executing Python Code.

How can I resolve this issue? I am using Windows 8.1 and QGIS 3.16.11 Hannover.

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\stackrasterbands.py", line 46, in stackAction
    self.stackRasters()
  File "C:\Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\stackrasterbands.py", line 87, in stackRasters
    cfg.utls.makeDirectory(cfg.osSCP.path.dirname(outputFile))
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 223, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\ntpath.py", line 185, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.16.11-Hannover Hannover, 26cc1c76 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.11/apps/qgis-ltr/./python
C:/Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS31~1.11/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.11\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16.11\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS31~1.11\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Comment: It is probably a bug. Open `C:\Users/hp/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\stackrasterbands.py` file. Comment 'Line 85' out by adding `#`. (that's, -> `#cfg.utls.makeDirectory(cfg.osSCP.path.dirname(outputFile))`). Save. Restart QGIS and try again. I'm unsure if it works. Maybe. Because `outputFile` is empty in source code.